# How to pass a variable from shell script to applescript

Tags: shell, applescript

I have a shell script that checks if folders have a set number of files and displays error messages to the user. I use applescript to display the error message. Is there a way to pass the variables of the shell script to the AppleScript?

Here is what I have:

```
declare -i count=5;
osascript -e 'tell app "Xcode" to display dialog "Counted $count items." buttons {"Continue"}'
```

I want the output to be `Counted 5 items.` but it just comes out as `Counted $count items.` How can I pass a shell script variable to the applescript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three solutions:

1. Use "" instead of '' so that the $var will be expanded by the shell
2. Close the quote, put the var, and reopen with no spaces (e.g. 'string'$var'rest of string'). However, this is unsafe if the variable can contain spaces.
3. [Use formal command line arguments](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050523140439734) with your AppleScript script

Comment: Cheers. I used the second method because I don't have spaces and it was the easiest to implement.

Comment: If var contains spaces, I found this to work: `osascript -e 'display dialog "string1'"$var"'string2"'`

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, this is what I did in the end to get it to work.

```
declare -i count=5;
osascript -e 'tell app "Xcode" to display dialog "Counted '$count' items." buttons {"Continue"}'
```